# How to Display ClassType Field into DataGridView

Tags: c#, web-services, datagridview, datasource, datagridviewcolumn

I have web-service function, which I'm importing for my project. The thing is that, I have method, which returns Array of (let's say) FirstClass. This itself contains field type of SecondClass (Members: Name, Value)
I have DataGridView with This Array DataSource. 
The thing is that, This MyDataGridView.DataSource = Array displays all field values excapt field type of SecondClass. (displayed Namespace.Class not the Value field)
what can i make to make Value field of SecondClass show.

Comment: What is the real type of the SecondClass here ?

Comment: Are you using `AutogenerateColumns=true` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Override the `ToString` method in the `SecondClass`.
- If you was unable to modify the `SecondClass` in any way, try to bind the `DataGridView` column to `SecondClass.Name` property.
- If that didn't work too, you can inherit `FirstClass` adding a property that gets the `SecondClass.Name` property's value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this [Article](http://www.developer-corner.com/development/dotnet/datagridview-how-to-bind-nested-objects/) helped

I could pass to DataPropertyName like FirstClass field (SecondClass Typed) Name.Name (Second Name - SecondClass Property)